# email delivery gets blocked if any one recipient email fromat is incorrect

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am facing a problem with mail delivery. My project is based on PHP application. I am using smtp to send mails . A group mail is sent from a email tool. If by any chance any one of the email address format withing the recipient group is incorrect (ex dora@yahoo) , then the email fails to get delivered.

What actually is blocking the email? Is it due to some PHP inbuilt mail function? Or does the smtp blocks it?

Please help me guys to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What kind of "email tool" are you using and how do you run it? Is it written by you, a third party component or even something non-php? If it's php how does it send the emails?

Comment: Hi,the email tool is php based. It is not written by me. Email tool uses a mail class to send emails. The mail class uses smtp and some mail functions to send email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem got solved. Actually the problem was due to one invalid email address present in the group of recipients.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your question is very vague.  I assume you do not get any error message when your script executes. Here is how I would handle this:

- First thing to do is make sure your error handling is set to [display
  errors](http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-display-php-errors-in-my-script-code-when-display-errors-is-disabled-t453.html).
- Reproduce the error -> run the script, if possible from the command-line with php -f *scriptname.php* and send it  malformatted emails.
- Either fix the script inline, or possibly better, ensure that emails that reach reach script have been validated. There are [many](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html) [php](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/13-PHP-Determine-if-a-given-e-mail-address-is-valid-.html) [tools](http://code.google.com/p/php-email-address-validation/) [available](http://code.google.com/p/php-email-address-validation/) for this.

If you just need a quick fix,  php's native [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) could be of some help.

- Last but not least, consider keeping a 'testscript' available that reproduces the steps you did above. You do not want to go through all this every time this thing chokes, and as my hero [the great rms](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) once said, if a job is worth doing once it is worth doing a tool that does the job for you.

Good-luck!

Comment: hey thanks..my problem got solved. Actually the problem was due to one invalid email address present in the group of recipients.